# Migrate/transfer from zimbra collaboration server GA 8.0.0 (zcs) to recent zimbra(zcs) GA

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, zimbra

Im using zimbra zcs 8.0.0 GA on ubuntu 12.04LTS , is it possible to migrate the settings/mailboxes from old zimbra to "new zimbra server". 
The new server have ubuntu 14.04.4 x64bit installed with  Intel Xeon CPU X3430  @2.40GHz and 15G of ram. I would appreciate any helpful suggestions or links. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

We did the same migration recently. It is definitely possible. Without much preparation it took us about 3 hours for a small server with about 30 users.
If your new servers performance is on par with the new server, there should be no problem with your setup.

[This manual](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/ZCS_to_ZCS_rsync_Migration) was the most helpful.
Ensure that your backup is up to date and complete. Pay very close attention to the `localconfig.xml` migration.

It seems likely that you might want to change the server hostname, which is not a trivial change for a Zimbra server. [This link](https://wiki.zimbra.com/wiki/ZmSetServerName) might be helpful.